# Piezo sensor requires parallel or pull-down resistor?

Tags: arduino-uno, piezo

Apologies but I didn't happen to find ultimate answer to this.

I'm trying to make a simple piezo sensor (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10293) which triggers something (e.g. a sound or lights up a LED) when it's pressed. This is similar to Arduino "Knock Lock" project.

However, I see there are 2 different basic ways to connect the piezo as vibration sensor:

**Way 1)** [as in Arduino project]

- Piezo + to 5V
- Piezo - to A0
- 1MΩ Resistor between A0 and GND

**Way 2)** [as in many other references on the internet]

- Piezo + to A0
- Piezo - to GND
- 1MΩ Resistor between A0 and GND

I tried both and have very different behaviours.

**Way 1** seems working correctly: `analogRead(A0)` returns a value related to how strong the vibration is, and then decays to almost 0 (I expected 0 but it stays to 50-60ish).

**Way 2** provide more of an impulse-type response, and stays at 400ish after triggered.

Are these behaviors correct and what's the proper way for piezo sensor?

Using Arduino UNO powered via USB.

Comment: what piezo sonsor are yout talking about?

Comment: @jsotola this one https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10293